# Payment Processing system implementation using Stellar API

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-laboratory

I am a software developer. I have a team of developers, and we are working together to create a new payment system in our country, as there is a monopoly of payment systems. We want to create a new payment processing company to compete with the existing ones. We want to add lots of new features as a startup, make this niche more competitive, and improve the user experience. Can someone tell us how we can use Stellar to create our payment processing company

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.